# Entity Framework Relations: Entity reference to each other

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

How to build correctly relations:

**Card** has an Owner, **Owner** has a Card.

```
Card:
- Id
- OwnerId
- Number

Owner:
- Id
- CardId
- Name
```

And when I'm updating Card's owner (OwnerId) I need automatically update Owner's CardId (remove previously and set CardId to new Owner)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score -1):

The best way to map a @OneToOne relationship is to use @MapsId.

```
@Entity(name = "Owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    ...
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

}
@Entity(name = "Card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Owner owner;

    ...

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

I am not sure if I understand your question but identities don't change over the time.

Comment: Ermm... this is a .Net question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it. But I think that the principle is the same.

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with Entity Framework or C# so it can't qualify as an answer.